# Cannot find module in React

Tags: json, reactjs

After pause in learning react (~1 year), i tried to create new app, but faced a necessity for updating npm version. Deciding to clear the cache and reinstall all materials - i get this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTRRd.png)

Maybe somebody had similiar problem? Previously - thanks for all.

Comment: Check if you have set PATH to global node moduls.

Comment: Don't put images as error message.